# how to work with google calender API in Nodes js and React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-calendar-api

my organization is creating a hotel booking website for another company. Apart from the website we are helping this company to create, They also have their rooms or spaces listed on the external website, Airbnb precisely. so they have the same spaces and hotels listed on the website we created for them and also in Airbnb. so we need to implement a way that won't allow their clients to book the same space or room at the same range of time. I.E if a client books a room at 9:45 am in the morning and will lodge only for 2 days, that room should no longer be available for the dates range the other user has booked it. So we decided to use the google calendar API as a middle man between our own website and AirbnB. if a user books any room or space in our website, on payment successful on the client at our ends here, The days the client wanna lodge should be added to the google calendar API to be exported to Airbnb and this should avoid bringing that consent screen google normally brings out to authenticate as we don't need to show anything to the client, we just want everything to be done underground. Most importantly I wanna do this using React.
I followed one node js video tutorial and he was able to create and read events successfully. he used the googleOauth2 playground API for authenticating. The API gave us a client Id, client Secret and most importantly a refresh token that would be used mainly to authenticate. This is the code below

```
// Require google from googleapis package.
const { google } = require('googleapis')

// Require oAuth2 from our google instance.
const { OAuth2 } = google.auth

// Create a new instance of oAuth and set our Client ID & Client Secret.
const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2(
  'YOUR CLIENT ID GOES HERE',
  'YOUR CLIENT SECRET GOES HERE'
)

// Call the setCredentials method on our oAuth2Client instance and set our refresh token.
oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
  refresh_token: 'YOUR REFRESH TOKEN GOES HERE',
})

// Create a new calender instance.
const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth: oAuth2Client })
```

I didn't post everything because the remaining codes is just creating events and the likes. So I was following this format to make the events work here in react but I was unable to pass the authenticate block in react.

```
According to the documentation for javascript
```

It states that I have to add the script src file below to make gapi works for javascript

```
 <script async defer type='text/Javascript' src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

But the problem now is how to implement the authentication using the refresh token available that was downloaded as json in react. The below code is how this was implemented using client and api key always showing windows for users to login before they can create events which in my case, I dont want

```
// Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      var CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';
      var API_KEY = '<YOUR_API_KEY>';

      // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"];

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";

 /**
       *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
       *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
       */
      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
          listUpcomingEvents();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

  function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        }, function(error) {
          appendPre(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
        });
      }
```

So the below is what have done but am stuck as I dont know what to else from here. I dont even know if what am doing is right or wrong

```
useEffect(()=>{
  gapi.load("client:auth2", () => {
      gapi.client
        .init({
          clientId: "myClientId",
          clientKey: "myClientKey",
        })
        .setToken({
          access_token:
            "myRefreshToken",
        });
    });
},[])
```

I need to get pass authentication to be able to create, read events in google calendar in REACT

Comment: If you don't want users to authenticate via a consent screen, you would have to use a service account with domain-wide delegation, but that would only be possible if all users were from the same Workspace organization. Also, I'm not sure about `using the refresh token available that was downloaded as json in react`, can you provide more details about how you retrieved the refresh token?

Comment: @Iamblichus According to the tutorial I was following, the guy used just one refresh token through out the adding and reading of events. And moreover I have a service account too, just that I don't know how to implement it

Comment: You are using client-side authorization, which doesn't support refresh tokens (see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow). You should use server-side authorization if you want to store and use refresh tokens (see the [Node quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/nodejs)) for more details on how to implement this. Please notice that each user would have to authorize at least once though, in order to first get the refresh token. Would this be appropriate for you? Does this answer your question?

Comment: One thing to note, the quickstart I provided is for command line applications. If you want to do a web application, take a look at [these examples](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#example) and [this guide](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#authentication-and-authorization).